# Dynamic variable subsititution using different suffixes for name in dictionary hierarchy

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In my `hostvars` structure I have a data structure like this for my web servers:
(This is only a snippet of the complete structure. Consider the structure "as set")

```json
{
    "wordpress": {
        "config": {
            "port": 80,
            "ssl": {
                "port": 443
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a kind of dynamic access to it, whether I'm using SSL or not.
Direct access is trivial — where host is the `inventory_hostname`; e.g. in a Jinja `for` loop:

```yaml
- debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[host].wordpress.config.port }}"
```

Restriction 1: The data has to stay in the hostvars dictionary, as I have to iterate over the hosts
Restriction 2: wordpress.config.port is only an example of a possible suffix. It could be also: openladap.whatever.anything.ldaps.port ...

Question is: can I have a dynamic suffix of the varible name like:
In other words: The suffix should be specified completely dynamically!
Like a pointer-to-member in C++

```yaml
- hosts: lb1 
  vars:
    host: web1
    suffix: '.wordpress.config.port'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[host] + suffix }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars',hostvars[host] + suffix ) }}"
```

Comment: Regarding "_Like a pointer-to-member in C++_" you may have a look into [Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials), Quote: "_**Think declaratively:** Ansible is a desired state engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming._"

Answer (score 1):

For me the data structure and approach looks unnecessary complex and clumsy. Since it seems you are looking for boolean state, if there is TLS configured or not, yes or no, true or false, a simple minimal example playbook could look like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    wordpress:
      config:
        ssl: true

  tasks:

  - name: Construct URL
    debug:
      msg: "http{% if wordpress.config.ssl %}s{% endif %}://wordpress.example.com"

  - name: With port if necessary
    debug:
      msg: "https://wordpress.example.com:443"
    when: wordpress.config.ssl
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Construct URL] *******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: https://wordpress.example.com

TASK [With port if necessary] **********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: https://wordpress.example.com:443
```

or for `false` just only

```yaml
TASK [Construct URL] **************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: http://wordpress.example.com
```

---

Regarding

> *...  this solution is not flexible enough ... Can I have a dynamic suffix of the varible name? ... In other words: The suffix should be specified completely dynamically! Like a pointer-to-member in C++*

Sure, you can add as much as you like ...

A simple minimal example with an inventory file **`example.com`**

```ini
[test]
test.example.com wordpress.config.port=443
```

and a playbook **`dyn.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    host: test.example.com
    suffix: 'wordpress.config.port'

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[host][suffix] }}"
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook --inventory example.com dyn.yml
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: '443'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this soluton is not flexible enough, as it sticks the the string "wordpress.config.port". I want to specify the suffix completey variable.

Answer (score 1):

Not like that. What you want is [`ternary`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ternary_filter.html) filter that selects one value or another based on condition:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ssl_enabled | ternary(hostvars[host].wordpress.config.ssl.port, hostvars[host].wordpress.config.port) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this soluton is not flexible enough, as it sticks the the string "wordpress.config.port". I want to specify the suffix completey variable.

Comment: This solution doesn't stick to any string because it doesn't use any suffixes at all. It just uses one variable or another. The closest to what you're looking for is probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77886502/16417367) but ultimately it boils down to reassigning and duplicating the variables. Not sure what advantage would it bring.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to change your data structure, you would probably be better applying some kind of database like normalisation to your JSON objet and achieve something like

```json
{
  "wordpress": { 
    "config": { 
      "http": { "port": 80 }, 
      "https": { "port": 443 }
    }
}
```

This way you can address your configuration in a easy fashion:

```yaml
protocol: https
port: "{{ wordpress.config[protocol].port }}" # 443, in this case
```

---

But if you really want to achieve it on your current data structure, Ansible provide you the [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/json_query_filter.html#ansible-collections-community-general-json-query-filter) filter that comes with a whole query language of JSON, called *[JMESPath](https://jmespath.org)*.

In JMESPath, given your `wordpress` variable, you could access the HTTP port with the query `config.port` and the HTTPS port with the query `config.ssl.port`, so you could effectively do:

```yaml
protocol: https
query:
  http: config.port
  https: config.ssl.port
port: "{{ wordpress | json_query(query[protocol]) }}"
```

---

And, of course, if you want to address it for another host, you can always swap out the plain `wordpress` for `hostvars[host].wordpress`.

---

As an example both this task

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ wordpress.config[protocol].port }}"
  vars:
    protocol: https
    wordpress:
      config:
        http:
          port: 80
        https:
          port: 443
```

And that one

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ wordpress | json_query(query[protocol]) }}"
  vars:
    protocol: https
    query:
      http: config.port
      https: config.ssl.port
    wordpress:
      config:
        port: 80
        ssl:
          port: 443
```

Would yield the expected:

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: '443'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this soluton is not flexible enough, as it sticks the the string "wordpress.config.port". I want to specify the suffix completey variable.

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic (whatever it might be) into the [vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). For example, into the *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
wordpress:
  config:
    port: 80
    ssl:
      port: 443

suffixes:
  http: "{{ wordpress.config.port }}"
  https: "{{ wordpress.config.ssl.port }}"

suffix: "{{ suffixes[protocol] }}"
```

Then, the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ 'host ' + suffix }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l localhost -e protocol=https

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: host 443

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```